# Shell Script : Join small gzipped files into larger files without unzipping them

Tags: bash, shell

I have some 8000 gz files of around 60MB each. I want to merge them into few larger files. So how to do it in a bash script **without unzipping them** ?

Shell script may take input as new-file-size or number of files to combine.

For example say I have 1.gz, 2.gz, 3.gz ... 10.gz
Now I need one file per say 3 files, so now 1.gz, 2.gz and 3.gz will combine into 1_new.gz and so on.

Comment: please edit your question to include what you have tried. Good luck.

Comment: One way to split an originally large file into smaller ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)

Comment: @shellter and Brian : sorry buddies I am not so proficient in shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to concatinate `gzip`ed files together, however when you  `gunzip` the resulting file you'll get a single stream, see the [gzip manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html#Advanced-usage) for reference.

A script would be similar to Ansgar Wiechers's one for `tar`:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxnum=$1
i=1
j=0
for f in *.gz; do
   cat $f >> archive_$j.gz
   i=$((i+1))
   if [ $i -eq $maxnum ]; then
      i=1
      j=$((j+1))
   fi
done
```

Note that the above code is untested.

If you want to archive things *properly* `tar` is a better solution, but if all you want to do is concatinate a number of files which have been `gzip`ed then such a concatination as this is good.

Comment: thanks man, this was enough :)

Answer (score 1):

`gzip` can only compress single files. You need `tar` to combine multiple files into a single archive, which in can then (optionally) be compressed with `gzip`. If you just want to merge the compressed files, you could use something like this:

```
maxnum=$1
i=1
j=0
for f in *.gz; do
  tar rf archive_$j.tar $f
  if [ $i -eq $maxnum ]; then
    i=1
    j=$((j+1))
  fi
done
```

That will produce a uncompressed tar files containing the compressed source files.

If you want to produce compressed tar files containing the uncompressed source files, the above won't work, though, because you can't update compressed tar files. You'll need to uncompress the source files first and then create a compressed tar file from them:

```
maxnum=$1
i=1
j=0
flist=
for f in *.gz; do
  gunzip $f
  flist="$flist $(basename $f .gz)"
  if [ $i -eq $maxnum ]; then
    tar czf archive_$j.tar.gz --remove-files $flist
    i=1
    j=$((j+1))
    flist=
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hey Ansgar, thanks for detailed reply :) But I just needed to combine a large number of gzipped files without uncompressing them into a few smaller number of files, that's it was required. If I wasn't clear I will edit the question.