# Gzip: merge a set of small files (<64mb) into several larger files (64mb or 128mb)

Tags: bash, hadoop, gzip, hdfs

I have around 14000 small .gz files (~from 90kb to 4mb) which are loaded into HDFS all in the same directory.

So the size of each of them is far away from the standard 64mb or 128mb block size of HDFS, which can lead to serious trouble (the "small files problem", see [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) blog post by cloudera) when running MR jobs which process these files.

The aforementioned blog post contains a number of solutions to this problem, which mostly involve writing a MapReduce Job or using Hadoop Archives (HAR).

However, I would like to tackle the problem at the source and merge the small files into 64mb or 128mb .gz files which will then be fed directly into HDFS.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Long back I had a similar question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233074/shell-script-join-small-gzipped-files-into-larger-files-without-unzipping-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting a bit further, the following two steps do what I want:

```
zcat small-*.gz | split -d -l2000000 -a 3 - large_
```

This works in my case, because there is very little variance in the length of a line.
2000000 lines correspond to almost exactly 300Mb files. 
Unfortunately, for some reason, gzip cannot be piped like this, so I have to do another step:

```
gzip *
```

This will then also compress the generated large files.
Gzip compresses each of these files by a factor of ~5, leading to 60mb files and thus satisfying my initial constraint of receiving .gz files < 64mb.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat small-*.gz > large.gz
```

should be enough. Assuming you don't need to extract separate files from there, and the data is enough.

If you want separate files, just tar it:

```
tar cf large.tar small-*.gz
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, both of your answers will result in one large gzip file. However, I would prefer a solution that Amar linked, however with the constraint that the files are as close as possible but smaller than 64MB (or optionally as close as possible but smaller than 128MB)

Comment: how do you want to extract data from such file? Just the data in general, or separate files too?

Comment: I only want to access the data itself. The files are each containing information in "line-by-line" style. They are fed to HDFS like this which will then uncompress them automatically. So I do not want to uncompress the data myself and it is not important which lines of the smaller files end up in which larger file.

Comment: In this case, just: `cat small-*.gz | split -b 64M -a 10 large.gz.`

Comment: I tried your snippet. However it can't find "large.gz.". After some digging around, the following worked: `$ cat small-*.gz | split -b 64M - large.gz_` Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120095/split-files-using-tar-gz-zip-or-bzip2

Comment: Sorry, change it to: `... |split -b64M -a 10 - large.gz.`